# How do I recreate the navigation function of Book Module while using Entity References?

Tags: entities, nodes

I'm recently been recreating a bunch of my sites functionality and decided to move away from Book module. It seems to get no love and nothing I need to work with seems to work with it for no apparent reason. So I moved over to just using Entity References.

I'm managed to recreate the Child page listing but I really need to add navigation to inside the structures as well. I need the next previous navigation links and I'm trying to create a jump menu for all entities that reference a story page.

I could use some advice, or documentation linking to somewhere to help explain more of this.

Comment: What defines a "next" and "previous" entity of another in your context? Are you thinking simply on entity ID?

Comment: Basically I have two fields in the content type these need to show up in. A "Chapter" has an entityreference field that references the "Story" and a chapter field that is an integer used for ordering. so if story equals cats and chapter equals 3 then next goes to cats - 4 and back goes to cats - 2.

Comment: I'm not positive but I think you'll need to code something for that manually - it's probably a bit of a niche requirement for a module to exist already to do it (or even if it did, it probably wouldn't be able to have a sophisticated enough UI to allow you to create such a complex rule for the navigation)

Comment: Book module did it, and if it wasn't so ignored I'd stick with it.

Comment: Entity References are not books, though, you shouldn't expect the same functionality out of the box

Comment: Maybe, but the answer should not be writing a custom module. This isn't something that should need any custom code. Surely there is a way to do this with views or something of that nature.

Comment: We'll have to agree to disagree; I suspect your requirement is complex enough that you'll need to write your own module. But you never know, there are many modules out there. It could be done with Views, but it'd need a custom pager (from a contrib module or otherwise)

Comment: WEll it seems I've found SOME options but I haven't been able to get them functioning just yet. I have Freepager that purports to be able to create a pager out of anything you can do in views but I haven't had it work yet. I got a jump menu functioning so if you are in a chapter you can select which chapter you wish to read but still no prev/next paging.